# Two-way binding Android on edit text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-jetpack

I want to set up the two-way binding for Edit Text. But getting an error so far.

Could not find event 'textChangeAttrChanged' on View type 'android.widget.EditText'

This is a pretty straightforward scenario but never seen a good working example.

Part of binding adapters:

```
 @BindingAdapter("textChange")
    @JvmStatic fun setText(view: EditText, value: String) {
        if (view.text.toString() != value) {
            view.setText(value)
        }
    }

    @BindingAdapter("textChangeAttrChanged")
    @JvmStatic fun setTextListener(view: EditText, onTextChange: ITextChange) {
        val textWatcher :  TextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                onTextChange.onTextChanged(view.text.toString())
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        }

        view.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "textChange")
    @JvmStatic fun getText(editText: EditText): String {
        return editText.text.toString()
    }
```

And from XML:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_title_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/input_address"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray"
                textChange="@={viewModel.searchKeyword}"
                textChangeAttrChanged="@{(text) -> viewModel.onSearchEntered(text)" // adding or removing this line doesn't give a thing
                tools:ignore="Autofill" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to use inverse databinding for a view model.

First, `EditText` already supports two-way databinding via the databinding library, so you don't have to do this on your own.

Second, you only need the inverse binding adapter stuff if you want to set up a custom view for databinding. In your case, you just want an existing view that is already set up for databinding to update your view moodel.

By using the `"@={viewModel.searchKeyword}"` notation, you are indicating that you have a property called "searchKeyword" that has both a getter and a setter and that you want the databinding library to invoke the setter with the value from the view when it changes.

Thus, all you should need to do is implement your logic in your property setter. Something like this:

```
@Bindable var searchKeyord : String? = null
    set(value) {
        if (field != value) {
            field = value
            onSearchEntered(value)
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.searchKeyword)
        }
    }
```

Please review the databinding documentation for more info.

Hope that helps!

Comment: In my ViewModel I have this field: searchKeyword = MutableLiveData<String>(). I've double checked default implementation of TextView Binding adapter and still wasn't able to find what's wrong with my code as it's quite similar: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/3b920788e90bb0abe615a5d5c899915f0014444b/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/TextViewBindingAdapter.java

Anyway, the correct answer is to use default implementation: android:text="@={viewModel.searchKeyword}